# How can I get django project run in https? and what actually is 'https'?

Tags: django, apache, svn, https, mod-wsgi

apache + python + mod_wsgi + django +svn:

I have alreaady get my django project running under http://. Then My boss ask me to get it run in https.

I would like to know what is the difference between http and https? And how can I make my django project run under https?

Thanks

`Oh sorry, I think I have to correct somethings here.

I got my boss wrongly. In fact, he wanted me to build and run django project with svn on apache server and he also wanted it running under https.

So, can anyone tell me or provide me some link of related information of how to setup these? (actually I have very little knowledge about what svn is doing. I think my boss wanted to use svn for managing the website source code.)`

*If possible, please tell more about svn. Thanks!

Comment: Point out to your boss it will cost money every year for the SSL certificate and see if she changes her mind.

Answer (score 4):

The Apache documentation has various documentation about HTTPS and setting it up to use it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/

You just need to put your mod_wsgi configuration within a VirtualHost setup for HTTPS.